# Animating overlapping imageviews is very slow

Tags: android, performance, imageview

I am seeing severe performance degradation when animating an imageview that overlaps another imageview. To test it I created an app with two imageviews (both 720x1280) placed vertically in a FrameLayout and mapped the position of the bottom view to touch events. If the views do not overlap then the rendering is very smooth. However, if I move the bottom image in front of the top one it gets very slow and choppy.

I've tried with hardware acceleration on and off, and HW acceleration turned on actually made it worse. Is there an easy fix for this that I'm missing? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I meet similar problem, although no the same. I overlap two imageviews and a scrollview aside them become very choppy.

Finally I found the problem isn't on overlapping. It's because both the two resource image has very large api and android has problem when renderring them. So I moved them from drawble folder to drawable-xxhdpi, and problem is solved.

May it helps.